# regular expression to remove ID=1234 from a string (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to create a regular expression to do the following (within a preg_replace)

```
$str = 'http://www.site.com&ID=1620';

$str = 'http://www.site.com';
```

How would I write a preg_replace to simply remove the &ID=1620 from the string (taking into account the ID could be variable string length

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know, where you get this string from, but this is not even a valid URI.

Comment: I know it isnt a valid url - it just some part of the process of system (too much to go into) i know it isnt a valid URL - the other part of the str_replace removes the ?page=something etc.. from the string
I should have probably put the original URL without this str_replace to make it clearer.

Comment: The point is: If it's a valid URI, you _definitely_ should parse it using `parse_url()`.

Comment: been banned from posting? what do I do now?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use...

```
$str = preg_replace('/[?&;]ID=\d+/', '', $str);
```

I'm assuming this is meant to be a normal URL, hence the `[?&;]`. If that's the case, the `&` should be a `?`.

If it's part of a larger list of GET params, you are probably better off using...

```
parse_str($str, $params);

unset($params['ID']);

$str = http_build_query($params);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that `&` is not allowed as a character in the `ID` attribute. In that case, you can use

```
$result = preg_replace('/&ID=[^&]+/', '', $subject);
```

or (possibly better, thanks to PaulP.R.O.):

```
$result = preg_replace('/[?&]ID=[^&]+/', '', $subject);
```

This will remove `&ID=` (the second version would also remove `?ID=`) plus any amount of characters that follow until the next  `&`  or end of string. This approach makes sure that any following attributes will be left alone:

```
$str = 'http://www.site.com?spam=eggs&ID=1620&foo=bar';
```

will be changed into

```
$str = 'http://www.site.com?spam=eggs&foo=bar';
```

Comment: +1 Gaz may also want `[?&]` instead of your first `&` in case it's the first thing in a query string.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
(that is ***if*** the URL is of the form: `http://something.com?id1=1&id2=2`):

```
$url = parse_url($str);

echo "http://{$url['host]}";
```

Comment: This will work nicely, so long as the OP doesn't ever want any GET params.

Comment: @alex it doesn't seem like the OP does want them, and even if he does, the OP can use the other array elements returned by `parse_url` to view them.

Comment: This would not work .... if the URL is `http://www.site.com&ID=1620` but if the url is `http://www.site.com?ID=1620` it would work `parse_url` can be easy confused when using `?` and  `&`

Comment: @Baba hmmm I did not see that the OP used `&`... Odd. I will update my answer.

Comment: wow guys - great response! Wish I could give you all the correct answer cos I learn stuff from all the posts! Thanks

Comment: @Neal ... glad i was able to help

Comment: @Baba There will _never_ be an URL like `http://www.site.com&ID=1620`, because that isn't an url...

Comment: @KingCrunch It does have to be a URL the question was specific to `http://www.site.com&ID=1620` the user might use such link with `explode` or remove `?` for security reasons and replace later